# Rollback of nested transaction throwing error in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to achieve. I have a nested transaction 'tran2', which I can't rollback

```
SELECT 'Before', * FROM [table] WHERE field ..

BEGIN TRAN tran1
UPDATE [table] set field ... WHERE field ..

 BEGIN TRAN tran2
    SELECT 'During', * FROM [table] WHERE field ..
    select @@trancount as 'transactioncount'

  rollback tran tran2

rollback TRAN tran1
SELECT 'After', * FROM [table] WHERE field ..
```

is throwing me this error

> Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Cannot roll back tran2. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.

however the `@@trancount` is giving me 2 transactions at that point

Comment: Read Paul Randal's [SQL Server Myth a day: nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282630%29-nested-transactions-are-real.aspx) - there is no support for nested transactions in SQL Server. Syntactically, yes - you can do it - but in reality, you never really have nested transactions....

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `begin trans tran2`, use [`save transaction tran2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx).

This creates a save point within the outer transaction, which you can rollback to.